# Python(scapy): how to sniff packets that are only outboun packets

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, packet-sniffers, sniffing

how do I sniff packets that are only outbound packets?
I tried to sniff only destination port but it doesn't succeed at all

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy indeed:

```
mac = get_if_hwaddr(conf.iface).lower()
sniff(lfilter=lambda pkt:pkt.haslayer(Ether) and pkt[Ether].src.lower()==mac)
```

If you want to print them:

```
sniff(lfilter=lambda pkt:pkt.haslayer(Ether) and pkt[Ether].src.lower()==get_if_hwaddr(conf.iface).lower(), prn=lambda x:x.summary())
```

You may use any other interface than `conf.iface`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get your device MAC address and filter any packets with that address as source address.